# For each row in pandas dataframe, create 4 new with different calculations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter, apply

I would like to convert width and depth dimensions into 4 corners of a polygon.
This means I should go from 1 row with width and depth dimensions to 4 rows with X,Y coordinates for each corner.

What is a good way to do this in Python with a pandas dataframe?

I tried creating each row manually and appending with apply (4 apply functions), but I know there must be a much more elegant solution.

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

| W | D |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 150 |
| 125 | 170 |

I would like one that looks like this:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 150 |
| 100 | 0 |
| 100 | 150 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 170 |
| 125 | 0 |
| 125 | 170 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>>
>>> list1 = [0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> list2 = [75, 100, 125, 150]
>>>
>>> combinations = list(product(list1, list2))
>>> for combination in combinations:
...     print(combination)
...
(0, 75)
(0, 100)
(0, 125)
(0, 150)
(0, 75)
(0, 100)
(0, 125)
(0, 150)
(0, 75)
(0, 100)
(0, 125)
(0, 150)
(0, 75)
(0, 100)
(0, 125)
(0, 150)
>>>
```

I think it's easier to do the calculations before, and then put the entries into a pandas dataframe after.